# Influenced Opportunities Related List on Campaign not showing Opportunities

Tags: page-layout, related-list, campaign

I have a Influenced Opportunities related list that is showing no opportunities on the Campaign page but when I click on the related list I can see the opportunity records.  The opportunities have "Primary Campaign Source" as the campaign record I am trying to display them on.  Any idea on why this would be happening?

[image: campaign]

[image: relatedlist]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this was I was choosing the incorrect "Campaign Influence Model Setup".
To show the desired records on the Campaign record, the Model must be set as "default" in setup